# Why does this import work?

Tags: python

The root folder for the `flask` (https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask) project (simplified) looks like this:

```
flask/
    __init__.py
    ... some more files ...
tests/
    test_basic.py
    ... some more files ...
```

The code in `test_basic.py`:

```
import flask
# some more code ...
```

How does this import succeed, since the `flask` package isn't a sibling of `test_basic.py` in the file tree? How does Python know where to find `flask`?

I *would* expect to see `from .. import flask`. But this isn't the case. Why does this work? Does it matter that the project uses `py.test` as the testing utitlity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This `import` imports the global `flask` from the `site_packages` directory and not your module.

If you will uninstall flask then you will get an `ImportError` exception.

Comment: And suppose `flask` *wasn't* in `site-packages`, and I still wanted to import it for testing in `test_basic.py`. What code would I need to write in `test_basic.py` to go about that?

Answer (score 4):

There are two possibilities. The first is that the flask project root directory is in your `PYTHONPATH`. If this is the case, then because there is an `__init__.py` file in the flask directory it's enabling the import of the entire `flask` module. 
The second (more likely) possibility is that Python is actually importing the `flask` module from your site_packages directory which you probably installed using something like `pip install flask`.